# sqlite error android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am always getting this error while creating database:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must be >= Version  0 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

Any idea how to solve this. My code is given below

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME   = "Exm"; 
    private static final String KEY_ID          = "id";
    private static final String KEY_USERID      = "userId";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME    = "userName";
    private static final String KEY_LOGINSTATUS = "userLoginStatus";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                                        + KEY_ID +   " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                                        + KEY_USERID + " VARCHAR (32) ,"
                                        + KEY_USERNAME + " VARCHAR (50),"
                                        + KEY_LOGINSTATUS + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
03-18 12:30:35.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 12:30:35.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1026): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must be >= 1, was 0
03-18 12:30:35.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:90)
03-18 12:30:35.077: E/AndroidRuntime(1026):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:69)
03-18 12:30:35.077:

Comment: Hi Anil M welcome to stackoverflow. Whenever you get some error, post the error log with your question, you will get proper response.

Comment: Once uninstall and reinstall your project, or clean it, I think some how your version is not changed, as previously it was giving "Version must be >=  0" and now its giving error "Version must be >= 1"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have declared `TABLE_USER`. I cannot see it in your code above.

Comment: that's not the problem ..i already declared ..but forget to add on the above code

Comment: Try cleaning the project and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling onCreate(db) from within onUpgrade().

If you want to re-use the code, put that piece of code somewhere else, and call that method from onCreate and onUpgrade.

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                                    + KEY_ID +   " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                                    + KEY_USERID + " VARCHAR (32) ,"
                                    + KEY_USERNAME + " VARCHAR (50),"
                                    + KEY_LOGINSTATUS + " INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
```

Keep this piece of code in another method, and call that method from within the onCreate and onUpgrade methods.